# How do I correct the package declaration for a set of classes under the same package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, package

I am moving a set of classes from one package structure to another.

Say I am moving the classes from com.oldstruct.oldpack to com.newstruct.newpack.

Is there any way to automatically change the package structure declaration for all the classes to the new package (com.newstruct.newpack) in Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse will do this for you. Refactor/Move.

Answer (score 0):

In package explorer right click on the package, choose refactor->rename type in `com.newstruct.newpack.`

Answer (score 0):

In project explorer just drag and drop the classes from one package to another.Eclipse will automatically correct the package declarations for all those classes.You can also refactor and rename the package name .Refactoring will automatically update all the references.